# Docker-swarm error: read-only file system

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have been trying to set up swarm using docker-machine. I created a swarm of three VMs using virtualbox driver (swarm-master, swarm-node-00, swarm-node-01) using docker-hub token.
Here is the info:

```
 [peeyush@localhost ~]$ $(docker-machine_linux-amd64 env --swarm swarm-master)
[peeyush@localhost ~]$ docker info
Containers: 6
Nodes: 3
 swarm-master: 192.168.99.103:2376
  └ Containers: 2
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 4
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 999.9 MiB
 swarm-node-00: 192.168.99.104:2376
  └ Containers: 1
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 4
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 999.9 MiB
 swarm-node-01: 192.168.99.105:2376
  └ Containers: 3
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 4
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 999.9 MiB
```

Now, the when I try to run a container using this swarm, I get this error:

```
[peeyush@localhost ~]$ docker run busybox echo "Hello World"
FATA[0029] Error response from daemon: Error pulling image (latest) from busybox, Mktemp failed: mkdir /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/graph/_tmp/2385573d8527cb02322beb23238c3d4bb1e35d4d6eec42ad0daa43b51a825eef: read-only file system
```

Could you please help me figure out, what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: It may be because your machine is not able to mount properly for the persistence storage in your VM.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the docker cannot allocate enough/any diskspace to build/run your image. It can happen while building or while running. Is your disk full? or do you need to sudo to run docker?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/graph/` is mounted as `read-only`. You can check how it was mounted.

Another thing I can think off top of my head is that you might want to re- configure (change) `docker/graph/` where stores docker configuration file, docker images, etc, to another place other than `/var/lib/`